# Attempting to use the syscall gettimeofday() to obtain a pseudorandom number in assembly on an armv7l , but registers go to 0 on syscall?

Tags: assembly, random, system-calls, raspberry-pi4, armv7

Once SWI #0 executes, r0 and the address represented by the label "time" do not have any value that's not null or garbage. I'm attempting to grab a single decimal number from the millisecond time value given from gettimeofday(2) syscall. This isn't intended to be cryptographically secure, and I'm constrained in terms of not being able use of the urandom file.

```
 timeofday:

    MOV r7, #78         @gettimeofday returns time
    LDR r0, =time       @address of holder for time_t
    MOV r1, #0          @timezone not needed
    SWI #0

_exit:
    MOV r7, #1         @exit syscall
    SWI #0

.data
time:   .space 8
```

Comment: Seems to work fine here. How do you know it's not working?

Comment: @Jester  When I look at my debugger, I can see that register r0 is set back to 0 on syscall. I assume this is due to it returning 0 on successful execution. But looking at the address location, the contents don't appear to make sense for what they contain

https://i.imgur.com/FRLFXCH.png

Comment: Looks correct to me. The seconds since epoch should be around 1616450000 and it is. The microseconds value can of course be anything (that is the very reason you are calling this function). You might be confused thinking "time of day" returns hours, minutes, seconds ... confusingly it doesn't :)

Comment: Probably better to use [`getrandom(2)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getrandom.2.html) which has been supported by Linux since 3.19, from 2015.  (The glibc wrapper is `getentropy(3)`, but `getrandom` is the underlying Linux syscall.)  If you need your code to work on older kernels, the normal way would be to `open` and `read` from /dev/urandom as you mention.

Comment: @Jester thank you, but I'm unsure what value in that screenshot is microseconds? Is it 47648?

Comment: @PeterCordes thank you for the suggestion, but my constraint as assigned is not using urandom which getrandom(2) does use in the backend.

Comment: Yes, the `47648` is the microseconds. It's the second word in the `struct timeval`.

Comment: You might be able to get 16 random bytes out of the [auxiliary vector](http://articles.manugarg.com/aboutelfauxiliaryvectors.html) which the kernel populates for you at program startup.  Search for type 25 (`AT_RANDOM`), see https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v3.19/include/uapi/linux/auxvec.h.

Comment: @NateEldredge: Oh neat, I didn't realize that existed.  http://articles.manugarg.com/aboutelfauxiliaryvectors.html shows a stack-layout diagram, and the fact that it's after the end of `envp[]`.